# MSSQL 2005 migration to 2008 Express Edition - Any complications?

Tags: sql-server-2005, migration, sql-server-2008

I've developed an application that uses ASP.NET, Linq-to-SQL and MSSQL 2005. However, I would like to migrate it to MSSQL 2008. I don't have MSSQL 2008, so I was wondering if it's possible for me to detach my 2005 db and attach it within 2008 express edition, to test if it will work on my host's MSSQL 2008 server? I haven't done anything complicated (CRUD is done from Linq to SQL, and all stored procs are the ASP.NET Membership default ones). Would this work, or will I get an error since I'm 'downgrading' so to speak? If I download MSSQL 2008 express edition, it will be on the same system as my MSSQL 2005 Developer Edition. I'm hoping this won't cause any problems?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be OK in this scenario. If you detach from your 2005 server, and reattach into 2008 Express, it'll work.

- Your DB will be in Compatibility level 90 for SQL Server 2005.
- Ensure you have a login associated with a user on that database.
- The only gotcha is that your DB must fit under the SQL Server 2008 Express limit of 4GB.

Try it out for yourself in a VM with SQL Express 2008. That'll eliminate any 2005 problems on your development machine.

**Update**: typically the average commercial host will supply SQL logins, rather than Windows credentials. It sounds like your host has provided you a Windows login. I guess the only suggestion would be to ensure that you have a User object in your database matched to the Login that your 2008 host has provided.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the noob questions, but what do you mean by 'login associated with a user on that database"? Up until now, I've been clicking on 'Windows Authentication' when connecting to the server. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should clarify that. I haven't uploaded to the host yet. The windows auth is on my dev machine. The host is providing MSSQL 2008, so I want to ensure my app works on 2008 before actually signing up.

Comment: @FullTrust Before you try out SQL 2008, try running SQL 2008 Upgrade Advisor to check if there are any upgrade issues installwise and mainly DB Scripts wise.

Also you cannot have two editions/instances of SQL with same Instance name. So in case the SQL Instance Name that your website uses cannot be changed, you would need to un-install SQL 2005 and install SQL 2008 with same instance name on your machine. In that scenario, a VM would greatly ease your pain. You can try out the free VMWare player to create the VM.